# How does one add additional items to NSMenu in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm using Xcode for the first time. I've been following a tutorial, and I'm completely stumped by something that's surely trivial. I've dragged a "Menu" from the Library into my "MainMenu.xib" window. Double-clicking this menu makes it appear.

[image: Default NSMenu in Interface Builder]

No trouble thus far. Editing the three items is intuitive, as is deleting items. How on earth do I *add* an item to this menu, though?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to drag an `NSMenuItem` from the library palette onto the menu:

[image: Library Palette]

You can add submenus and separators similarly.

Comment: Thanks, Barry. It'll take me a while to get used to the fact that drag and drop seems to be the only way to do certain things in Interface Builder. When I get lost I tend to start right-clicking on things, which wasn't at all helpful on this occasion.

Comment: @davidchambers Welcome to the Mac ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Cmd-D duplicates anything as well if you are getting tired of the drag-drop thing.
You just have to watch out that as your tags and action connections are getting duplicated too they might not be connected to the thing you wanted them to be.