# Adding menu to your Mac apps in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one add additional items to NSMenu in Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511817/how-does-one-add-additional-items-to-nsmenu-in-interface-builder)

There's something that blocks me from doing my project in mac. How can I add or create additional menu to my app?

The defaults are file, edit, help, etc. but how can I add my custom menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drag and drop menu items to and from the main menu in Interface Builder.

Comment: To add a menu to the menu bar, you'll want a Submenu Menu Item. A menu item without a submenu (i.e., with no menu) won't be too useful.